# How secure are cookies for auto logging in a user?

Tags: php, cookies

I understand there are other questions on how secure cookies are in general but was wondering about their security in this particular scenario and if there is a better way to go about it.

I have a whole system where the user can log in and view data for a team that they are part of. I was using sessions but have decided to transfer to use cookies instead as this allows the user to be automatically logged in if they are returning to the page (say the next day) in much the same way as you can on websites like facebook.

I have a function that checks for cookies on the user's computer when they enter a page and logs them in if they already have a cookie (while refreshing the admin cookie as this one only lasts a day due to the ability to remove admin rights). I was wondering how secure cookies were in this way and if someone could manipulate cookies to log in or to make themselves an admin.

```
function checkForCookies() {
        if (isset($_COOKIE["username"])) { // Sees if the user has already got a cookie from logging in recently
            if (isset($_COOKIE["admin"])) { // Sees if admin cookie is set as this has a shorter expiry as it is more important if changed
                header('Location: ../HomePages/HomePage.php');
            }
            else {
                $tempCon = new DBConnect();
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = :username";
                $stmt = $tempCon->conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_COOKIE["username"]);
                $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                    setcookie("admin", $row->Admin, time() + 86400, "/", "", true, true);
                }
                header('Location: ../HomePages/HomePage.php');
            }
        }
        else {
            header('Location: ../Login/Login.php');
        }
    }
```

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors like TLS and specific settings in PHP. I would read up, OWASP is still good for these topics: https://www.owasp.org/images/a/a0/OWASPLondon20171130_Cookie_Security_Myths_Misconceptions_David_Johansson.pdf Then as far as implementation you get into things like session fixation and things like session regen on privilege elevations, reauth of user on certain actions, etc... It is not a simple subject.

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks for the pointer, I'll be sure to read into it

Comment: What I said above is more advanced than what you were inquiring about. As answer below suggests, never store values like that in the cookie. The cookie should act as an identifier for session data. Think of the cookie as being a better way to maintain the session id, if you had no cookies you would accomplish the same by taking on `?PHPSESSID=foo123bar` to every request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you store something what an attacker could guess in the cookies (like `username=bob` or `admin=true`), this is really insecure. Cookies are sent to the server by the client and an attacker can interfere on what cookies are sent to the server (by changing this in the browser or manually sending an http request). Thus he can send any cookies he wants to send, e.g. sending a cookie header with `admin=true`.

The contents of sessions on the other hand are stored on the server side and can't be manipulated by the user.

Comment: I get that sessions are more secure but for wanting to keep the user logged in they're not the best option as they end when the browser is closed and I want the user to stay logged in. In this case, could i remove the admin cookie and get that from the database each time i need it and just use the username and team values that are the other cookies?

Comment: The "session" data does not go away when the browser is closed. The session is deleted after the cookie expires, typically at least, see `session.gc_maxlifetime` and `session.cookie_lifetime`. You need to read up more on this topic - think there is something you are not quite grasping.

Comment: I think that because I was calling session_start at the beginning of each page when using sessions, that got rid of the old session meaning that the user couldn't stay logged in after reopening the browser.

Comment: @ficuscr If I now understand, changing the `gc_maxlifetime` sets how long until they time out of the session for inactivity and `cookie_lifetime` is how long the session will last, similar to using `time() + (86400 * 30)` for the expiry of a cookie for 30 days?

Comment: Pretty much. A good way to learn this is to write [your own session handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php). A class that implements the [SessionHandlerInterface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php). Write one to work against a MySQL table. Play with configuration, observe what happens, in code and with the persisted data in the database. Another option is looking at how some popular frameworks do it. It will click for you soon - think you are almost there, just confused on a couple points.

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how professional my way is but i am using this :
you can create a column in the users table at your dataBase for identifier .
each time a user successfully signs in , you can create a random hash and update his record in DB , putting this hash as his identifier , and also set a cookie for him with the identifier hash.
so next time user opens your web site you can check if cookie isset , if so , you can search your DB for a record with that identifier , if found , get the record and put in a session and use it in your scripts . also each time a user signs out and again signs in , identifier is a new hash . so no one can guess another users identifier to set as cookie and perform a CSRF attack .

```
<?php  
         // example for creating a random string as identifier :
        $randomByte = random_bytes(15);
        $identifier = bin2hex($randomByte);
        setcookie('identifier', $identifier, (time() + 86400 * 30),'');

   // example for remembering user 
    if (isset($_COOKIE['identifier']) && !is_null($_COOKIE['identifier']) && !empty($_COOKIE['identifier']) && !isset($_SESSION['userSignedIn'])) {
        $cachedIdentifier = $_COOKIE['identifier'];
        $userFoundByID = $usersInstance::selectByIdentifier($cachedIdentifier);
        if (!empty($userFoundByID) && !is_null($userFoundByID)) {
            $user = $userFoundByID[0];
            $_SESSION['userSignedIn'] = $user;
        }
?>
```